# Steema Teechart Series X axis values overlapping

Tags: vb.net, winforms, teechart

I am using Teechart pro for one of my vb.net Winform project.. 
I am getting one issue regarding x axis values, all values are overlapping and no gaps between them.
Below is the screenshot for reference.
[image]

Can anyone suggest me which properties or axis or method I should work on to resolve this issue? 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

LineGraph.Width work in my case.. Implemented the same and problem resolved.